# Add fixed attribute to XmlElement without a wrapper class

Tags: c#, xml, xmlserializer

I have class of the following sample structure:

```
public class DataClass{

    public String Field1{ get; set; }
    public Int32 Field2{ get; set; }
    public Int32 Field3{ get; set; }

}
```

I have to add a fixed attribute for every field, so that the output looks like:

```
<DataClass>
   <Field1 code="code#1">Value of Field1</Field1>
   <Field2 code="code#2">Value of Field2</Field2>
   <Field3 code="code#3">Value of Field3</Field3>
</DataClass>
```

Is this possible without writing a wrapper class for every Field?
Something like:

```
public class DataClass{

    [XmlElement(FixedAttribute="code#1")]
    public String Field1{ get; set; }

    [XmlElement(FixedAttribute="code#2")]
    public Int32 Field2{ get; set; }

    [XmlElement(FixedAttribute="code#3")]
    public Int32 Field3{ get; set; }

}
```

Kind Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, XML attributes do not provide such capabilities. One option is to have `DataClass` implement `IXmlSerializable`. This gives you full control over the output XML. You have to serialize all properties yourself, but since you have to supply the code attributes for each property anyway, it's not so bad. If you have a lot of `DataClass`es you might consider creating a custom attribute to decorate properties with and moving the serialization logic into a base class or, if a common base class for all `DataClass`es is inconvenient, putting it into a separate helper class. `IXmlSerializable.WriteXml` would then call this custom logic. If you control `DataClass`es, I think this is the better option.

A more hacky alternative is to create a wrapper for `DataClass` that would delegate the serialization of the wrapped `DataClass` object to the regular XML serializer, but substitute a custom `XmlWriter` that would add your XML attributes to the XML elements corresponding to properties.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and the hints. I will write my own serializer.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a custom serializer rather than use the built in serializer using Xml Linq

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication49
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XElement dataClass = new XElement("DataClass");

            for(int i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
            {
                XElement field = new XElement("Field" + i.ToString(), new object[] {
                    new XAttribute("code", "code#" + i.ToString()),
                    "Value of Field" + i.ToString()
                });
                dataClass.Add(field);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom xml writer:

```
public class DataClassWriter : XmlTextWriter
{
    public DataClassWriter(string url) : base(url, Encoding.UTF8) { }

    public override void WriteStartElement(string prefix, string localName, string ns)
    {
        if (localName.StartsWith("Field"))
        {
            base.WriteStartElement(prefix, localName, ns);
            base.WriteAttributeString("code", "code#" + localName.Substring(5));
        }
        else
            base.WriteStartElement(prefix, localName, ns);
    }
}
```

Using:

```
var xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(DataClass));

using (var writer = new DataClassWriter("out.xml"))
    xs.Serialize(writer, data);
```